# Intent pass two or more extras in anko kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, anko

I'm a little bit confuse about how to add more extras to the intent when i'm using a kotlin library called anko. Is there any way to put two or more extras to it?
Here's my code:

```
view.context.startActivity(view.context.intentFor<DetailsActivity>("name" to "nameTextView"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code its working perfectly

```
startActivity(intentFor<DetailsActivity>("id" to 5,"name" to "Test"))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
var intenttest = Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java)
intenttest.putExtra("test" ,"value")
intenttest.putExtra("test1","value1")
intenttest.putExtra("test2","value2")
startActivity(intenttest)
```

and for anko use this

```
startActivity(intentFor<SecondActivity>("id" to 5,"test" to "value"))
```